# Connect Windows Mobile to client PC over WIFI

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, windows-mobile

What would be the best way to transfer a string across a network from a windows mobile device(so .net) to a .net app running on a pc on the same wifi network?

Would normal sockets work or would i use something like a webrequest?
The client can be any version of .net.

Thanks

Comment: Sockets should work just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For application there is no matter what type of connection is used, because it is incapsulated inside net-related classes.

On desktop you may use

- TcpListener http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx
- HttpListener http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx
- WCF
- Web Service
- ASP.NET Handler

These classes allows you to map some URL like http://{PC-name}/somepath to code executed by your applcation.

On mobile device you may use some classes allows you to make request using that URL. Also if your desktop application publish web service or WCF service, you may add reference to this service to mobile application and get strongly-typed interface to operate with desktop application. It is preferred way as for me.